# inicializacao de Thread usando interface runnable

Tags: java, thread

Estou com um problema na criação de umas threads:

O erro é:

> "The method AtualizaProdutoRunnable(Filial, List,
>   ArrayList) is undefined for the type Principal"

na classe Principal:

```
for (Filial filial : listaFiliais) {
        Thread threads = new Thread(AtualizaProdutoRunnable(filial, listaProduto, listaVendas));
        threads.start();
    }
```

na classe AtualiaProdutoRunnable:

```
    package negocio;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AtualizaProdutoRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Filial filial;
    private List<Produto> listaProduto = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    private ArrayList<Venda> listaVenda = new ArrayList<Venda>();

    public AtualizaProdutoRunnable(Filial filial, List<Produto> listaProduto, ArrayList<Venda> listaVendas) {
        super();
        this.filial = filial;
        this.listaProduto = listaProduto;
        this.listaVenda = listaVendas;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Venda venda : listaVenda) {
            if (venda.getFilial().getCodigo() == filial.getCodigo()) {
                Produto produtoVenda = venda.getProduto();
                for (Produto produto : listaProduto) {
                    if (produtoVenda.getCodigo() == produto.getCodigo()) {
                        if (produto.getQuantidade_estoque() - 1 >= produto.getQuantidade_minima()) {
                            produto.setQuantidade_estoque(produto.getQuantidade_estoque() - 1);
                            System.out.println("Produto: " + produto.getNome() + " da filial " + filial.getNome() +" da venda "+ venda.getCodigo() + " Foi decrementado!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Alguém consegue me explicar o que tenho que fazer?

Comment: Adicione o código da classe onde está o método `AtualizaProdutoRunnable`.

Comment: Mas espera, `AtualizaProdutoRunnable` no seu código não implementa `Runnable`, não é só por isso no nome e pronto, você tem que atender o "contrato" da interface, que nesse caso é implementar o método `run`.

Depois, você tem que instanciar um objeto novo para enviar para a thread, precisa do `new` ali, a mensagem de erro mesmo diz que `AtualizaProdutoRunnable` está sendo reconhecido como método e não objeto:

`Thread threads = new Thread(AtualizaProdutoRunnable(filial, listaProduto, listaVendas));`

Comment: Falta um `new` antes de `AtualizaProdutoRunnable`: `new Thread(new AtualizaProdutoRunnable(...))`.

Comment: @Renan estou me sentindo um idiota, muito obrigado

Comment: @taq cara estou muito envergonhado do meu erro ter sido algo tão pequeno assim, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo

Comment: Dá nada não. :-)